# Help in determining prediction accuracies over the life of a customer

Tags: prediction, count-data, accuracy

I have been tasked with determining the accuracy of some data, however my statistical knowledge is weak and I am hoping to be pointed in the proper direction. For a customer, we have a series of predictions that they have made regarding the attendance for their events, as well as the final actual attendance count. We would like to be able to examine the historical data for a customer and be able to say they underestimate their attendance by, say, 15% or overestimate by 18%. What would be the best way to approach this? This could then be applied against upcoming events they have, to try to more accurately predict turnout.

Data would be:

```
(predicted, actual)
(12, 18)
(60, 80)
(300, 375)
```

Comment: Where did these predictions come from? What was the model used? Do you have any information other than two counts?

Comment: You might also describe what your goals are with this model and the costs of being wrong in either direction.

Comment: The predicted value is provided by the organizer of the event. The goal is to try to more accurately estimate real monthly activity versus what the organizer thinks will happen initially. As far as the costs of being wrong go, no major decisions will be made with this data initially. We will compare predicted counts versus final counts at the end of each month for a few months to ascertain how close the model is.